# can we use forfiles command to hide files based on modification time?

Tags: cmd

I'm trying to hide the files in a folder based on the modification time. I'm using the below command to hide. Once I run this command, all files become hidden irrespective of the modification time.

```
forfiles /P . /C "cmd /c attrib +h" /D +01/15/2019
```

Comment: Because you are not using any of the `FORFILES` variables to specify what file to use with the `ATTRIB` command.  You are basically telling it to do all files.  Open up a command prompt and type: `forfiles /?` to learn what variables you can use.

Answer (score 0):

As you've not responded to [@Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman)'s comment, here is your fixed command line, including the relevant 'variable':

```bat
ForFiles /D +01/15/2019 /C "Cmd /C If @IsDir==FALSE Attrib +H @File"
```

This should hide all files, (subject to permissions), in the current working directory, which were last modified on or since 15th January 2019, using the regional date format MM/dd/yyyy. *Please note, as the date format used above is region specific, this command line will not necessarily be useable on any PC.*

In future, please remember that the usage information for Windows built-in commands is available, when you open a Command Prompt window and enter the command with the question mark option, e.g. `ForFiles /?`.